# check if value exists in array

Tags: laravel

I have 2 queries and I want to check if values of one queries exists in array of other query. I have "maintenance" which has "process_id" and "processes" (array of process id's). I want to check for each process_id if exists in processes. in my controller:

```
$processes = DB::select('select id from processes');
$maintenance = DB::select('select process_id from maintenances where car_id ="' . $id . '" group by process_id');
        $result = array();
        foreach ($processes as $key => $value) {
            $result[] = $value->id;
        }
```

In my Helper.php

```
public static function array_value($value, $array) {
        $results = 0;
        $str = "$value";
        if (in_array($str, $array)) {
            $results += 5;
        } else {
            $results += 1;
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

In my view

```
 @foreach ($maintenance as $m)                         
          <tr> @if (Helpers\Helper::array_value($m->process_id, $processes)== 5)
               <td>   {{ $m->process }} </td>
                @elseif (Helpers\Helper::array_value($m->process_id, $processes)== 1) 
                  <td>Missing</td>    
                   @endif
          </tr>                                                 
  @endforeach
```

And it displays only values in the first if. It doesn't displays Missing when process_id isn't found in array processes

Answer (score 1):

If you're using laravel have you considered setting up a relationship to make this task simpler?

I assume process and maintenance will have a one to many relationship?

You could set up a many to many relationship:

**in your process model:**

```
public function maintenance() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Maintenance')
}
```

(where Maintenance is the name of your model class. The function name can be anything)

**In your maintenance model:**

```
public function process() {
    return $this->hasMany('Process')
}
```

Then your revised model retrieval is:

```
$maintenance = Maintenance::find($id);
```

UPDATED:
    $maintenance = Maintenance::where('car_id', '=', $id)->first();

```
$maintenance->load('process');

(you could chain these)
```

Then in your view:

```
@if($maintenance->process()->first())

{{$maintenance->process()->name}} //or whatever positive output

@else

"NO process found" //or your negative output

@endif
```

The relationship does the hard work for you - you also then have the properties of the related mode available such as name etc which may be more user friendly.

the `first()` method retrieves the first related model. if this is null (ie not found) then the negative response works. YOu could also use `count()` which may be better then use:

```
@if($maintence->process()->count() > 0)
```

but all depends what you want to do.

YOu can also explore the get() method which will return a collection, useful if you expand your relationship to a many to many eg each maintenance may have many processes/

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for response. It shows this error in my controller: Call to a member function load() on a non-object    at this line:      $maintenance->load('process');

Comment: and dd($maintenance) shows NULL and I don't have a construct, what should I put there?

Comment: if $maintenance is null then it's not found your maintenance model with the id specified. The find() method looks for the model with an id and searched the id column - just re-read your question and your searching on a different column. You'll need to change the approach - just updated the answer

Comment: now it shows Call to a member function process() on a non-object  at line @if($maintence->process()->first()) in my view. Also I want to check for distinct process_id, is this included ?

Comment: there's a spelling mistake! $maintence should be $maintenance

Comment: explain me something: I should have maintenance_id at table "processes" and "process_id" at "maintenances". Which means that any time a maintenance is added its id should be saved at processes? So how to check if for a specific car the process id is missing? I am confused

Comment: Because it never shows error. It now displays only results. Table "processes" is supoused to have all processes not repeating and if I add maintenance_id here it should be repeating processes and I dont know how to check for a missing process?

Comment: I'm not clear on your business logic for your app. You can query for maintenance table for entries with or without a process using the has() method. YOu can find out more here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations.

Comment: well what I want is: for a specific car in maintenance table to check if is missing one of processes in table "processes". Because each car should have at least one time process stored at maintenance table, If not it should warn the user. I read what u sent but I don't know if it helps me.

Comment: should I countinue with your answer or it doesn't what I want?

Comment: is the relationship between maintenance and process a many to many? If count() ===0 then no related processes exist for that maintenance table. Your sample code suggested you only wanted to know whether a process exists or not. In a one to many relationship you'll only need maintenance_id in the porcess table. you can query the related model for a specific id with $maintenance->process()=>where('column', '=', 'something' have a look at these references: http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-relationships and http://www.ashwinsureshkumar.com/laravel-querying-where-on-eloquent-relationships/